# Exchange Server 2007 - Windows Integrated Authentication

Tags: exchange-2007, authentication, sharepoint-2007, integrated-authentication

I'm trying to get Exchange Server 2007 to work with Windows Integrated Authenticated unsuccessfully. At the moment it's working with Basic Authentication.

I followed the instructions in [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998638(EXCHG.80).aspx) but where it says "To modify an Exchange 2007 virtual directory, select Server Configuration, select Client Access, and then click the Outlook Web Access tab. The default Exchange 2007 virtual directory is /owa", I have nothing in there, no virtual directory. If I go to IIS and switch the authentication from Basic to Integrated for the OWA virtual directory, I cannot login anymore.

The goal is to have Sharepoint's OWA web part connecting to Exchange without having to login to owa. The credentials should be passed from the sharepoint site to owa.

Anyone knows why I don't have the virtual directory in Exchange, or why changing the authentication in IIS doesn't do the trick?

Thank you in advance